# asp.net MVC3.0 : callbacks for use with HTML.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, html.beginform

I am using HTML.BeginForm to upload files. This part works fine.

However, in addition to uploading files, I would like to populate a field on the same page with the name of the file selected.

Is there any way to do this?

edit: I am seeking to know the name of the file uploaded (after the upload happens).

Comment: Do you mean a name specified by the user, or the file name of the uploaded file?

Comment: before or after the post and file upload?

Comment: Name of the file uploaded (after the upload).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **jQuery .change** to append the name of the selected file to the div/area you want to display it

```
$('#myFile').change( function()
{
  var uploadeFile= $(this).val();
  //Append uploadedFile to a div/area
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" />
```